# Migrating a single branch from SVN to Git

Tags: git, svn

I have 5 branches in my old SVN repository and I want to migrate only one branch to my new Git repository.

Path of SVN branch to be migrated: `http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/svn/myRepo/branches/firstBranch`.

When I am running this command:

```
git svn clone http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/svn/myRepo --no-metadata --stdlayout  --branches branches/firstBranch --prefix origin/ --trunk .
```

...it checks out complete repository. But I need to get one branch in my Git repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `--stdlayout` or `--branches`. Simply do `git svn clone  http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/svn/myRepo/branches/firstBranch .`.